# Can I add custom GraphQlWebSocketMessage as "start", When I try to executeSubscription?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-graphql

I'm trying to executeSubscription using WebSocketGraphQlClient

```
webSocketGraphQlClient.document("subscription onCommentsAdded { comment}")
            .executeSubscription().
            .subscribe();
```

Springboot version 2.7.10

When above subscription is executed, I'm getting invalid message as the server is expecting "start" as type.
Using Insomnia, I tried with type as "start", it is working

2023-04-12 10:03:38.326 DEBUG 39728 --- [ient-SecureIO-2] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonEncoder  : Encoding [GraphQlWebSocketMessage[id="1", type="subscribe", payload={query=subscription { (truncated) ...]
2023-04-12 10:03:38.430 DEBUG 39728 --- [ient-SecureIO-2] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonDecoder  : Decoded [GraphQlWebSocketMessage[id="1", type="error", payload={message=Invalid message type!}]]

Is there any way to change type as "start"?

I tried adding Serializer to jackson2JsonEncoder to update type, but its not working as its checking enum type

Comment: Can you share your schema.graphqls ?